# Каким образом можно обработать нажатия на элемент если над ним ScrollView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

В layout есть элемент (GridLayout), который находится под другим (ScrollView). В ScrollView есть другой элемент с заданным значением layout_marginTop так, чтобы первый элемент (GridLayout) был виден. Каким образом можно обработать нажатия на GridLayout если над ним ScrollView?

Я хочу чтобы информация при прокручивании ScrollView закрывала GridLayout (при этом он оставался на месте, там описание и стрелка для возврата назад). Если на примере, то есть лист бумаги с надписью в верхнем углу. Над ним другой лист бумаги и при перемещении верхнего листа, он может закрывать надпись на первом или открывать.

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".InformationActivity">
    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_container_favouriteAdd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:rowCount="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/back_arrow_info"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/itemInfo"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </GridLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
            android:background="@drawable/corner_shape">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="24dp"
                android:paddingRight="24dp">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="290dp"
                    android:layout_height="290dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

                    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/picture_InformationActivity"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_photo_size_select_large_black_24dp" />
                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
                </FrameLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name_InformationActivity"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                    android:text="@string/infoAcivity_sample"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textSize="26sp" />

                <!-- a lot of TextViews -->


            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Переформулируйте пожалуйста вопрос, а то не совсем понятно что именно вам нужно сделать. А так просто по id повесьте на нужный элемент вам слушатель: findViewById(R.id.bottom_container_favouriteAdd).setOnClicklistener(/* здесь выполняете нужные вам действия*/)

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужен [NestedScrollView](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/nestedscrollview.php)

Иерархия примерно такая:

ScrollView1

-LinearLayout

--GridView(высота wrap_content)

--ScrollView2(высота match_parent)

---содержимое scrollView2

Comment: Получилось что весь контент двигается одновременно. Вышло то же самое, что и (в скобках уровень вложенности):

(1)ScrollView
(2)LinearLayout
(3)GridLayout
(3)остальное содержимое

Comment: Видимо я вас неправильно понял. Вы хотите, чтобы контент закрывал таблицу? Тогда даже не знаю что предложить... Разве что костылировать, например положить во frameLayout таблицу, поверх нее ScrollView, в котором первым элементом будет невидимая view с размерами как у таблицы

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте поиграться с параметром  android:translationZ. Например, на одной из вьюх поставьте android:translationZ="1dp".